# Flex Error #1074: Illegal write to read-only property Property on Module

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I keep seeing errors like these in my logs and believe it may be affecting a data grid sort I am trying to do. Any idea on what I should be looking for? a google search pulls up a lot of people writing about the problem but no fixes.

```
#1074: Illegal write to read-only property Object on Module
```

here is an example of the code I think is causing it although it seems really basic I think this is where it happens and that object is read only and trying to be set.

```
public function get objectName():String
{
    if(object)
        return object.name;
    return '';
}
```

Comment: That piece of code is fine as long as object is defined and has a name property. Can you provide a small sample that actually has the problem?

Comment: Flash Builder doesnt show me what line the problem occurs on it just shows the error like 100 times when I load the page and then sorting that column does not work properly with everything being identical to other columns.

Comment: Yea I know I am asking what I should be looking for in that error because there doesnt seem to be a lot of data on the matter.

Comment: somewhere in your code look for    `xx.Object =` where xx could be anything

Comment: Showing your `Module` class code might help as well

Comment: If you run it through the debugger you should be able to get the line number

Comment: could you explain how. it is running in debugger but it doesnt stop the program and does a trace just writes the title to the console.

Comment: Where are you debugging it? (Flash Builder? Flash Develop? Browser?)

Comment: Flash Builder my debugger only says things if it stops the application with warnings or errors. This just gets written to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for an instance of class Module, where you're trying to set a property called Object.

so let's say in your code somewhere you have variable `mod:Module`. The error is saying your trying to do something like this:

```
mod.Object = someValueThatDoesNotMatter;

//OR possibly

mod["Object"] = someValueThatDoesNotMatter;
```

But the Object property of the Module class is read-only. But seeing as `Object` is a primitive type keyword, it will probably never work.

If you post more code a better answer can be given.